# JAVA-Error of int cannot be dereferenced?//toString

Tags: java

I have no idea on how to fix this?I'm new to java and still learning

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            BufferedReader read=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.print("\nInsertion Sort");
            System.out.print("\n\nEnter number you want to Sort: ");
            int max = Integer.parseInt(read.readLine());

            int[] numarray = new int[max];

            for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
            {
                System.out.print("\nEnter [" + (i + 1).toString() + "] element: ");//error in toString
                numarray[i] = Integer.parseInt(read.readLine());
            }
```

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what is wrong -- you cannot call a method from an int, a primitive. So change `(i + 1).toString()` to simply `(i + 1)`.

Comment: yeah hahahaahah im so dumb.all fix